# How my simple sub-query work when a aggregate function and a Group by clause is used?

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, having, correlated-subquery

I have homework problem sorry I am very noob in this.

I have an Employee table.
I want a Query to find the Name of an employee drawing highest salary in their departments

I have written:

```
Select emp_name 
from employee 
where salary=any(select max(salary) from employee group by dept_no)
```

[image: [enter image description here]]

Table Name: employee

```
emp_name  salary   Dept_no
e1         1000     10
e2         2000     10
e3         2000     20
e4         3000     20
```

output should be :

```
e2 
e4
```

but it is wrong as can someone tell me why ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing the link of the departments and sets the condition only for salaries.
You must join your subquery to the table:

```
Select e.emp_name 
from employee e inner join(
  select dept_no, max(salary) salary
  from employee 
  group by dept_no
) t on t.dept_no = e.dept_no and t.salary = e.salary
```

Or with NOT EXISTS:

```
Select e.emp_name 
from employee e 
where not exists(
  select 1 from employee
  where dept_no = e.dept_no and salary > e.salary
)
```

Comment: what my understanding is the group by divides the dept no into groups and then max salary is selected from each group and then this max salaries is given to outer table ...use in (..) instead of =any

Comment: Correct, but `where salary=any(...)` compares every employee's salary to all the max salaries of each group. So employee e3 from dept_no = 20 has salary 2000 and because his salary is equal to the max salary of dept_no = 10 this employee will be selected in the results by your code.

Comment: Thank you I just forgot that where condition check-in every row so 2000 compare with every row and e3 will be displayed .....I don't know but my mind is stuck Thinking that outer query will just display the results of the inner query...If there is just a print command in SQL this would have been easy, any method without using a correleted query you have just given ?? Also thank you for this !

Comment: Any solution would be like: `Select e.emp_name from employee where ...` and the condition after `where` should involve the max salaries for each group which must be selected. So one way or another, even with window functions, you must use a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue that that there is no connection between the departments.  So, someone in Department B might earn the maximum salary of someone in Department A -- but might not be the highest earner in that department.

For this approach, I would recommend a *correlation clause* in the subquery, rather than `GROUP BY`:

```
select e.emp_name 
from employee e
where e.salary = (select max(e2.salary)
                  from employee e2
                  where e2.dept_no = e.dept_no
------------------------^ correlation clause
                 );
```

Note the use of table aliases and qualified column names.  You should *always* qualify all table references when writing queries -- it ensures that the query does what you intend and it makes the query more understandable for others.

If performance is an issue, then use `employee(dept_no, salary)`.

Comment: This *correlation clause* will execute the subquery over and over for each emp_name. So why do you recommend it?

Comment: @forpas . . . You simply do not understand how query optimizers work.  Correlated subqueries are sometimes the *fastest* way to write query logic.  I would suggest you learn about optimizers, indexes, and how databases really work.

Comment: What you seem you don't understand is that you should not *recommend* a solution which needs to be optimized to perform (at best) equally like the GROUP BY solution when there is already a solution that does not need to be optimized.